# How to search for a string in all stored procedures through SQL Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a bunch of stored procedures in my database, I launched the `PowerShell` for SQL Server by right clicking on the `Stored Procedures` folder in `SSMS` and choosing `Start Powershell`, I tried the following command but it gives me nothing

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYCOMP\DEFAULT\Databases\MYDB\StoredProcedures> Get-ChildItem |  ForEach-Object { (Invoke-SQLCMD -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query  ("sp_helptext '$_'" )) | Select-String mykeyword}
```

If I remove the `| Select-String mykeyword` part, it spits out the code for every stored procedure one by one. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is returning an array of PSCustomObjects that have a string property named "Text". You need to pipe the value of that property to select-string. Right now you are calling select-string on an object that is not a string. Change to:

```
Get-ChildItem |  ForEach-Object { (Invoke-SQLCMD -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query  ("sp_helptext '$_'" )) } | Select-Object Text | Select-String yourKeyword
```

To answer your later question about outputting the sp name, you could store the name in a variable and output it, something like:

```
$sName = '';
Get-ChildItem |  ForEach-Object { $sName = $_.Name; (Invoke-SQLCMD -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query  ("sp_helptext '$_'" )) } | Select-Object Text | Select-String yourKeyword | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $sName }
```

Comment: How would this be changed if I want to write-host the name of the stored procedure, not the line where the string was found?

Answer (score 2):

I see that there's already an answer, but this was slightly more useful to me:

```
Get-ChildItem |  ForEach-Object { if(($line=Invoke-SQLCMD -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query  ("sp_helptext '$_'" ) | Where Text -like  '*Title*'| select -expand Text)) {$_;$line}}
```

I'm outputting the stored procedure objects as well as the matching lines (interspersed).  It would probably be worthwhile to make this into a function and package the output as objects but this is a good start.